# Magento 2 change colours

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cli, less

I am trying to change the colours from the standard Magento 2 blank theme via the **`_theme.less`** file. I currently have the following file structure **`/public_html/app/design/frontend/GladiatorFitness/Gladiator`**

```
- registration.php  
- theme.xml  
- web
-- css  
--- source
---- _theme.less  
---- _typography.less
-- fonts  
-- images
```

In my **`_themes.less`** I have added the following the following, and I have attempted to clear caches, and deploy assets. Nothing seems to make a difference.

```
//  Primary button
@button-primary__background: @color-orange-red1;
@button-primary__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
@button-primary__color: @color-white;
@button-primary__hover__background: darken(@color-orange-red1, 5%);
@button-primary__hover__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
@button-primary__hover__color: @color-white;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a **_variables.less** file in the source folder of css codes. Try adding your codes there. Then you will see the change in colors.

Answer (score -1):

After applying your theme, make sure you are in a **`developer mode`** (when flushing cache)

- Go to your **Magento Admin** .
  Then go to **System > Tools > Cache Management** and **click** **Flush Static Files Cache.**

  Or
- Manually clear the **`pub/static`** and **`var/view_preprocessed`** directories and **`subdirectories`** except for **`pub/static/.htaccess.`**

After clearing cache, run **`static-content:deploy -f`** (to force deployment)